# CGAffineRotation Skews Image Photos

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uideviceorientation, avcapture

My iOS has registered for device orientation change notifications via `NSNotificationCenter`, and has a method that responds to the different orientation changes.  The following code is called to change the orientation and location of a view when rotating the phone to "landscape-left".

```
camAngle = [(NSNumber *)[_cameraToggleButton valueForKeyPath:@"layer.transform.rotation.z"] floatValue];
            camDegrees = (RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(camAngle));
            if (!(camDegrees == 90)) {
                _cameraToggleButton.alpha = 0.0;
                _cameraToggleButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90));
                _cameraToggleButton.frame = CGRectMake(274, 350, 66, 54);
                [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
                [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
                [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
                _cameraToggleButton.alpha = 1.0;
                [UIView commitAnimations];
            }
```

And my equations to convert radians and degrees:

```
#define RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(radians) ((radians) * (180.0 / M_PI))
#define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle) ((angle) / 180.0 * M_PI)
```

The view rotates correctly and assumes the correct position on screen, but the sides of the image are suddenly squashed, making the image look condensed.  This only happens when rotating the phone into landscape position (left or right).  Rotating to upside down or back to portrait translates and rotates the view fine, with essentially the same code.  What could cause this skewing of the images in landscape position?

Comment: Does this image have any autoResizingMasks set?

Comment: More importantly, what is the `contentMode` of the view being rotated? If it's `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill` that may explain part of your problem.

Comment: Yes! Content mode is Scale To Fill. What impact could that have on the app?

Comment: Would "Aspect Fit" be a better option? I suppose I see how the former could be a complication when rotating the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not set the `frame` of the `_cameraToggleButton` after you set the rotation transform on it. To re-position the _cameraToggleButton after you set the rotation, you should change it's `center` like so:

```
_cameraToggleButton.center = CGPointMake(274, 350);
```

Also, as someone else suggested, use `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` instead of `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill`.